# can someone explain me this error #error 35 #error directive

Tags: stm32, stm32f0, keil

i would like to know if someone can help me on this issue

I have two lines nearly the same, the only difference is "!" before the condition ( if .... is good but not if ! ....)

error:  #35: #error directive: "define interrupt type NM_EDGE_INTERRUPT,NM_LEVEL_INTERRUPT"

Thank you

Comment: If you actually read the text of the error, it seems fairly clear that you haven't defined the interrupt type to be either EDGE, or LEVEL. Choose the one that's appropriate for your needs and define it. You probably shouldn't be adding or removing any "!" characters in the code if you don't understand it.

Comment: You were lucky to get a definitive answer to such a question, really.

Comment: I _absolutely_ loathe these types of questions. People **_really_** need to learn how to troubleshoot their code. I understand if you don't know the syntax of a programming language but to ask about an error where you think you've hit a brick wall is rather unacceptable. The chances that someone else on the internet has run into the same problem is nearly 100%. That being said, I _highly_ encourage you to research the problem on the internet. It's there _somewhere_. You're not discovering gold when you find issues in your code. Please utilize STMicroelectronic's website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is a complete lack of research shown

Comment: @KingDuken, people that do not read the comments are worse.

Answer (score 4):

The code has an `#error` directive, **explicitly** telling the preprocessor to throw an error if it hits the line.

These are put in by the programmer, reminding you that something is required otherwise it won't compile or work.

In this case: `"define interrupt type NM_EDGE_INTERRUPT,NM_LEVEL_INTERRUPT"`.